# Cinder volume creation failing on openstack

Tags: openstack, disk, cinder, openstack-cinder

The following is the output of `heat-engine.log`. It says that 
ResourceInError: resources.sdc_volume_data: Went to status error due to "Unknown"

```
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 INFO heat.engine.resource [req-c6dfeeec-ec2e-404b-a1c9-aadf516ab4e6 - admin - - -] CREATE: CinderVolume "sdc_volume_data" [1bdc9d36-a5f7-4e85-a1b2-8e3727819170] Stack "ssrr" [0dbada33-0c90-4230-b0e4-bae2dc04a455]
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 776, in _action_recorder
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     yield
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 878, in _do_action
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     yield self.action_handler_task(action, args=handler_args)
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/scheduler.py", line 352, in wrapper
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     step = next(subtask)
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 829, in action_handler_task
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     done = check(handler_data)
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/resources/openstack/cinder/volume.py", line 301, in check_create_complete
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     complete = super(CinderVolume, self).check_create_complete(vol_id)
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/heat/engine/resources/volume_base.py", line 56, in check_create_complete
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource     resource_status=vol.status)
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource ResourceInError: Went to status error due to "Unknown"
2018-07-04 15:15:47.684 33906 ERROR heat.engine.resource
```

Please tell what could be the reason of the error.